# Simulate DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, foreign-key, cascade

I need to delete many rows from one table persons, that is referenced by many other tables as FK.

If I had DELETE CASCADE, I could just delete the records from persons, and automatically delete from the other tables, but I don't like the idea.

I would like a script that takes as input a DELETE statement, and outputs all the DELETE statements that are needed. Ideally, it would tell me how many records would be deleted.

Example:

Input:

```
DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_id < 1000000
```

Output:

```
-- This would delete 124,345 records
DELETE FROM persons_addresses WHERE person_id < 1000000
-- This would delete 82,954 records
DELETE FROM persons_phone numbers WHERE person_id < 1000000
...
-- This would delete 999,999 records
DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_id < 1000000
```

Comment: My goal is to delete records, a FK pointing to person can prevent me from doing it.
SELECT will not help, I need all the DELETE from the referencing tables.

Comment: Can the input be provided as strings, like `'dbo.persons'` and `'where person_id < 1000000'`? What about the case where the column name involved in the foreign key is different between child and parent?

Comment: Of course it is provided as string. And in my database, I try to keep column names unique as much as possible, so child and parent have for sure different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information required to generate the queries and the counts is all available in the catalog views, like `sys.columns` and `sys.foreign_key_columns`. We need to find all of the child tables, and then count how many rows in each child table meet the same criteria as the parent ID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GeneratedPathedDeletes
  @ParentTable     nvarchar(512),
  @ParentColumn    nvarchar(128),
  @DeleteCriteria  nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',
          @src nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ''DELETE $t$ WHERE $c$ $clause$;'' UNION ALL SELECT 
          ''-- This would delete '' + (SELECT RTRIM(COUNT(*)) FROM $t$ WHERE $c$ $clause$) 
          + '' rows.'';';

  SELECT @sql += REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@src,N'$t$',t),N'$c$',c),N'$clause$',@DeleteCriteria)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT t = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(pt.parent_object_id))
             + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(pt.parent_object_id)),
           c = QUOTENAME(pc.name)
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns AS pt
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS pc
       ON pt.parent_object_id = pc.[object_id]
      AND pt.parent_column_id = pc.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS rc
       ON pt.referenced_column_id = rc.column_id
      AND pt.referenced_object_id = rc.[object_id]
    WHERE pt.referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@ParentTable)
      AND rc.name = @ParentColumn
  ) AS x;

  -- final delete of parent table:
  SELECT @sql += REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@src,N'$t$',@ParentTable),
    N'$c$',@ParentColumn),N'$clause$',@DeleteCriteria);

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
EXEC dbo.GeneratedPathedDeletes
     @ParentTable    = N'dbo.persons',
     @ParentColumn   = N'person_id',
     @DeleteCriteria = N' < 100000';
```

My sample tables were much smaller, but my output looked like this:

```
-- This would delete 12 rows.
DELETE dbo.persons_addresses WHERE person_id < 1000000;

-- This would delete 4 rows.
DELETE dbo.persons_phone_numbers WHERE person_id < 1000000;

-- This would delete 2 rows.
DELETE dbo.persons WHERE person_id < 1000000;
```

Limitations:

- This doesn't perform the deletes - you still have to run those manually based on the output.
- This doesn't handle cyclic paths or grandchildren; only traditional parent-child.
- This doesn't handle multi-column keys or, probably, self-referencing keys (didn't even try).
- More complex clauses, like an IN clause, or multiple ranges, will require more work.
- This isn't secure from SQL Injection - if you're accepting weapons from users and passing them into this procedure, please see my tips [part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such tool, but you can easily create one your self ([foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1151/identify-all-of-your-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database/)):

```
SELECT C.TABLE_CATALOG [PKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
       C.TABLE_SCHEMA [PKTABLE_OWNER], 
       C.TABLE_NAME [PKTABLE_NAME], 
       KCU.COLUMN_NAME [PKCOLUMN_NAME], 
       C2.TABLE_CATALOG [FKTABLE_QUALIFIER], 
       C2.TABLE_SCHEMA [FKTABLE_OWNER], 
       C2.TABLE_NAME [FKTABLE_NAME], 
       KCU2.COLUMN_NAME [FKCOLUMN_NAME], 
       RC.UPDATE_RULE, 
       RC.DELETE_RULE, 
       C.CONSTRAINT_NAME [FK_NAME], 
       C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME [PK_NAME], 
       CAST(7 AS SMALLINT) [DEFERRABILITY] 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC 
     ON C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS C2 
     ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2 
     ON C2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA 
    AND C2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND KCU.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION 
WHERE  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
  AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
  AND C.TABLE_NAME = ?
```

will give you all the children of the root table. You can create a recursive CTE that computes all offspring to this table.

As for the number of rows affected, you can construct it like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT T.*
    FROM T
    WHERE EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM <JOIN ALL TABLES FROM PARENT OF T TO ROOT>
         WHERE ROOT.PREDICATE
    )
) AS X
```